# off to a week's vacation

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, expressions, phrases

> I just need to get to Boston and then I'm off to a week's vacation.

When would it be natural to use 'off to a week's vacation'? Can it be used if you just have a week off from work or only if you're going somewhere on vacation in your week off?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be one of those where BrEng & AmEng have different 'rules'.

"off to a week's vacation" - never in BrEng.
Even if we were to substitute 'holiday' for the US 'vacation'.

You go **on** holiday/vacation, not 'off to' it.
You could go "off **for** a week['s holiday]" but you get away with 'for' in this case because it refers to the week, not the holiday.

You can be off work, and on holiday.
You can even, in some dialects, be "off on holiday next week", but that's a special case which uses 'off' to mean 'go & shouldn't be used generally outside of the areas that have that dialectical usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's natural. Another alternative is:

> I'm off **for** a week's vacation

And it's usually used for *real* vacations, not so much for a week off from work. Otherwise it heavily depends on context, in your case it's obviously a real vacation. Plus, a week off from work is enough to have a short vacation! (Unlikely)